# How can make my game support touch screen?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, 2d-games

I have done a wheel game from a tutorial. The problem is the game works perfectly with a mouse but does not work on touch screens. I don't know how to manipulate it to transform the game.

How can I adapt the game to function with touch screens?

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import com.greensock.TweenMax;

    public final class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var speed:Number = 0;
        private var paddles:Vector.<Sprite> = new Vector.<Sprite>();
        private var line:Shape;
        private var lastPaddle:String;

        public final function Main():void
        {
            paddles.push(wheel.p1, wheel.p2, wheel.p3, wheel.p4, wheel.p5, wheel.p6, wheel.p7, wheel.p8, wheel.p9, wheel.p10);
            listeners('add');
        }

        private final function listeners(action:String):void
        {
            if(action == 'add')
            {
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDraw);
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, spinWheel);
            }
            else
            {
                stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDraw);
                stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, spinWheel);
            }
        }

        private final function startDraw(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            line = new Shape();
            addChild(line);

            line.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
            line.graphics.lineStyle(8, 0x000000, 0.3);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, drawLine);
        }

        private final function drawLine(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            line.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        }

        private final function spinWheel(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, drawLine);
            listeners('rm');

            speed = line.height * 0.1;
            removeChild(line);
            line = null;

            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, spin);
        }

        private final function spin(e:Event):void
        {
            /* Rotate Wheel */

            wheel.rotationZ += speed;

            /* Detect Value */

            for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if(indicator.hArea.hitTestObject(paddles[i]))
                {
                    lastPaddle = paddles[i].name;
                }
            }

            /* Decrease speed */

            speed -= 0.1;

            /* Remove lIstener and reset speed when wheel stops */

            if(speed <= 0)
            {
                stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, spin);
                speed = 10;
                run(lastPaddle);
                listeners('add');
            }
        }

        function run(action:String):void
        {
            switch(action)
            {
                case 'p1':
                    myText.text = "text 10";
                    break;
                case 'p2':
                    myText.text = "text 25";
                    break;
                case 'p3':
                    myText.text = "text 20";
                    break;
                case 'p4':
                    myText.text = "text 50";
                    break;
                case 'p5':
                    myText.text = "text 30";
                    break;
                case 'p6':
                    myText.text = "text 75";
                    break;
                case 'p7':
                    myText.text = "text 40";
                    break;
                case 'p8':
                    myText.text = "text 100";
                    break;
                case 'p9':
                    myText.text = "text 50";
                    break;
                case 'p10':
                    myText.text = "text 125";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.NONE;** will render your application to read touches as mouse input: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html#inputMode

Answer (score 4):

first of all set in stage :

> Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT

after that
just replace MouseEvent to TouchEvent and replace MOUSE_DOWN to TOUCH_BEGIN and 
MOUSE_UP to TOUCH_END. after that you must change MouseEvent in event handler to TouchEvent
and if you have using MOUSE_MOVE chenge that to TOUCH_MOVE

```
  private final function listeners(action:String):void
    {
        if(action == 'add')
        {
            stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, startDraw);
            stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, spinWheel);
        }
        else
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, startDraw);
            stage.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, spinWheel);
        }
    }
```